# masking QT widget while capturing the screen

Tags: qt, capture, screen-capture, image-capture

I have a Qt 4.8 application for both Win and Mac that captures the screen.

I have a QT widget on my desktop (always on top) that *shouldn't be captured during my capture*. Instead of the QT widget, the application/desktop running behind the QWidget should be captured. My QT application's UI should be masked from capturing.

Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/desktop-screenshot.html - the Qt screenshot example does this...

Comment: @Mat Thanks. First of all I'm not capturing using QT rather I'm using bitBlt (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm using QT only for displaying UI. 
EDIT:Second, in this program, they have used hide() before capturing and show() after capture. Actually this doesn't work out in my code as I want to show it always. I want to know whether is there any hooks I can place in the QWidget to get it masked while taking screenshot

Comment: So? Look at how it's done in the Qt docs, you can apply that to your method of screen cap.

Comment: In the above program, they have used hide() before capturing and show() after capture. Actually this doesn't work out in my code as I want to show it always. I want to know whether is there any hooks I can place in the QWidget to get it masked while taking screenshot

Comment: @Mat Sorry for the EDITS, some keyboard issue

Comment: So this is not a qt question at all. Its related to your specific screen cap approach an how it performs the cap. BitBlt i think just takes a portion of the buffer. Your option is to hide the window first.

Answer (score 0):

The main question is: are you in control of taking the screenshot or not? If you're taking the screenshot, it'd be doable but platform specific. You'd need to get the contents of all of the windows on the screen except the one you don't want to see, and build up a screenshot from those.

If it's a third party screen grabber, like Ctrl-PrtSc on Windows or Grab on OS-X, then you're out of luck unless the OS provides some APIs that would enable you to hide the widget.

The functionality you desire isn't exactly commonplace so I'm doubtful there's any portable, or even sane, way of achieving what you want.